# VueSlickCarousel change all the slides totally in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using VueSlickCarousel to create a slider which is able to change list and count of slides base on  a defined button clicked.

```
    <button @click="slides = 10">10</button>
    <button @click="slides = 5">5</button>
    <button @click="slides = 15">15</button>
```

I'used v-for on slide in slides

```
    <VueSlickCarousel :arrows="true" :dots="true" style="height: 300px">
      <div v-for="n in slides" :key="n" style="height: 300px">{{ n }}</div>
    </VueSlickCarousel>
```

whenever i change slides the component misbehaviour cause slider to miss usability( extra dots , wrong width measurement , extra white-space , unexpected slides loop , ... )

there is a sandbox example project here
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-brook-47wbn

v-if is not the the propper solution , although v-show may work but cause the carousel to blivk.

is it something related to nuxt or VueSlickCarousel ?
is there any solution to reinitiate component upon to new list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying, but it looks like you have to update the component to take in a new value for number of slides. In the docs they mention a reInit event you can use to init the component again. Before doing this you have to set the new value for the number of slides to your data variable. For example:

```
<button @click="numberOfSlides = 10; reInitSlider()">10</button>
```

Re-init method:

```
methods: {
    reInitSlides() {
        this.slider.reInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna update list of slides.
I tried ```ref=carousel``` on VueSlickCarousel component.
```this.$refs.carousel.reInit()``` return not defined function or variable error.

Comment: If you do `console.log(this.$refs.carousel);` will it show up something? Also, you could put on some events according to the docs [here](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/docs/API.md#all-events). You could put a @init or @reInit event on the component. In the function, you could console.log some, and check if it is triggered.